# if condition in mysql function

Tags: mysql, join

how to call if function with three different parameter.like

```
`get_Eingehende_Anrufe_overall`('startdatum','Enddatum'), else `get_Eingehende_Anrufe_topic`(Campaign,'startdatum','Enddatum'),
`get_Eingehende_Anrufe_teams`(id,'startdatum','Enddatum')
```

Comment: could you post full query?

Comment: Maybe you are asking about how to use the Function If? if so, try this [MySql If Function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php), this function takes three parameters and you can use it in a query outside of a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
if else command in mysql is like this:

IF (condition1) THEN
  get_Eingehende_Anrufe_overall('startdatum','Enddatum');
ELSEIF (condition2) THEN
  get_Eingehende_Anrufe_topic(Campaign,'startdatum','Enddatum');
ELSE
  get_Eingehende_Anrufe_teams(id,'startdatum','Enddatum') ;
END IF;
```

... if you want to use it within a function;

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' FUNCTION get_Eingehende_Anrufe_all
(
  cond INT(2), 
  id INT(4),
  Startdatum Varchar(255),
  Enddatum Varchar(255)
) 
RETURNS int(15) 
BEGIN 
  declare RETURNVAL integer(15); 
  IF (cond = 1) THEN 
    SET RETURNVAL =    get_Eingehende_Anrufe_overall('Startdatum','Enddatum'); 
  ELSEIF (cond = 2) THEN 
    SET RETURNVAL = get_Eingehende_Anrufe_topic(Campaign,'Startdatum','Enddatum'); 
  ELSE 
    SET RETURNVAL = get_Eingehende_Anrufe_teams(id,'Startdatum','Enddatum'); 
  END IF ; 
  RETURN RETURNVAL;
  END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have given 'root' as username and 'localhost' as database host. You have to use correct username and hostname. if local database then 'localhost' else you have to user ip address of database.

Also username should be existing.